# Удаление элементов массива javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Требуется удалить элементы массива от позиции1 до позиции2

к примеру 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 (позиция1 = 1; позиция2=3) получим массив (0 1 3 4 5 6)

split ом не выходит

Comment: Читайте прилагающиеся мануалы: http://javascript.ru/array/splice
Вопрос повторяющийся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этих целей используется метод `splice` с двумя аргументами: начальный индекс удаляемых элементов и число удаляемых элементов. Например

```
a.splice( 2, 1 )
```

удаляет один элемент с индексом 2.

Метод возвращает объект массива с удаленными элементами.

Вот демонстрационный пример

```
<!DOCTYPE html />

<html>

<head>
    <title>Array splice</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

        alert("Original a: " + a.toString());
        //  or alert("Original a: " + a);

        var b = a.splice(2, 1);

        alert("After deleting a: " + a.toString());

        alert("Array of deleted elements b: " + b.toString());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

То есть если вам требуется удалить элементы в массиве между элементами с индексами index1 и index2, то вы пишите

```
a.splice( index1 + 1, index2 - index1 - 1 );
```

где index2 > index1.

Comment: А если удалить надо элементы между двумя любыми позициями?

Comment: @Visman  Просто берете разность двух позиций в качестве второго аргумента при условии, что первая позиция - это также позиция удаляемого элемента. Иначе увеличиваете на 1 значение первой позиции и только затем берете разность позиций для подсчета числа удаляемых элементов.

Comment: вы бы это в ответе написали ;)

Comment: @Visman Написал.:)